# How I can create a text area that will always resize?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How I can create a text area that will always resize when I will resize the main window? Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about layout managers in Swing. You can use a GridBagLayout and assign your JTextField the desired weight and fill. Basically, create a GUI using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) documentation as an example and play around with the options.

Comment: I will do how you said :)